# some services switched off automatically

Tags: debian, postfix, vps, cron, ftp

with my company we have a VPS. We have some issues with it.
this morning the pure-ftpd was stopped. I had to start also postfix and the cron jobs were off for 3 hours.

My config : Debian GNU/Linux 7

I have some questions about this :

1. is it correct to start the cron server using the command :
   "/etc/init.d/cron start" ?
2. where can I get logs of what happened ? How can I solve this ?
3. Do you have any solutions to detect this kind of problems ?

I have basic knowledges on how to administrate a server, so maybe I don't understand some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly to your question:

1) yes

2) have a look at the log files for those services under ***/var/log*** . The second part of the question depends on what you will find in the log files and trace the cause of this behaviour.

3) you can use **monit** -> http://mmonit.com/monit/ 
From the website:

> Monit can act if an error situation should occur, e.g.; if sendmail is not running, Monit can start sendmail again automatically or if apache is using too much resources (e.g. if a DoS attack is in progress) Monit can stop or restart apache and send you an alert message. Monit can also monitor process characteristics, such as; how much memory or cpu cycles a process is using.
>
> You can use Monit to monitor daemon processes or similar programs
>   running on localhost. Monit is particular useful for monitoring daemon
>   processes, such as those started at system boot time from /etc/init/
>   For instance sendmail, sshd, apache and mysql.